# boundaries per category in a separate (static) fact table

Tags: data-warehouse

I need some help to design the star schema of a process where the fact table contains unique products delivered at different dates on different locations. The product may belong to category-level1, category-level2.

Now there are some hardcoded values for category-level1, category-level2 and the product for every calendar year: min-target-category and max-target-category.

And there are some hardcoded values for location and category-level1, category-level2 and the product for every calendar year: min-target-region-category and max-target-region-category.

The business users expect to browse the data:

- by category and year: the count(product) metric should be between target-min and target-max.
- by region and category and year: the count(product) metric should be between target-region-min and target-region-max.

One possible approach is to define two other fact tables where the grain is (Year,category,[region]) and of course the two numeric values: target-min, target-max.

Is it enough? Can be modeled in a different way?

Thank you for you time!

PS: there are limits (min and max boundaries) for all three levels : category-level1, category-level2 and product itself - because Rich asked for adding the product to the static table. Thanks!

PPS: yes , of course. I have appended two sets below:

For the calendar year 2010:

category-level1 ; category-level2 ; product ; min-target ; max-target
 100 ; N/A  ; N/A        ; 50 ; 500
 100 ; 1001 ; N/A        ; 40 ; 400
 100 ; 1001 ; 1001-prodA ; 5  ; 50
 100 ; 1001 ; 1001-prodB ; 2  ; 10

region-code; category-level1 ; category-level2 ; product ; min-target ; max-target
 Region-NORD ;  100 ; N/A  ; N/A        ; 40 ; 400
 Region-NORD ;  100 ; 1001 ; N/A        ; 30 ; 300
 Region-NORD ;  100 ; 1001 ; 1001-prodA ; 4  ; 45
 Region-NORD ;  100 ; 1001 ; 1001-prodB ; 2  ; 10

For eachcalendar year there are two tables with values like above.

Comment: Would your possible approach cater for individual products, because you mentioned there are targets for those too?

Comment: Can you include sample values?  Do you store the level 1 & 2 attributes in your product dimension table?